# Render a newline in my data inside a jqGrid cell

Tags: css, jquery-ui, formatting, jqgrid, newline

First off, I'm using version 3.7.1 with a jQuery UI framework theme.  I'm trying to figure out how to have a newline or even a `<br />` render inside of a jqGrid cell.

**An example of what I'm looking to have happen:**

```
________________________________________________________
Item 1     |   some data   |  Applies to OS 1
                              Applies to OS 2
                              Applies to OS 3
                              Applies to OS 4
__________________________________________________________
Item 2     |   some data   |  Applies to OS 1
__________________________________________________________
Item 3     |   some data   |  Applies to OS 4
                              Applies to OS 5
__________________________________________________________
```

**What currently happens when my data has either a `<br />` or a \n is:**

```
__________________________________________________________
Item 1     |   some data   |  Applies to OS 1Applies to OS 2Applies to OS 3Applies to OS 4
```

I would rather not have to use an actual `<br />` tag, since I'd rather not have HTML embedded in my data, but am willing to do whatever I have to since I NEED to render this data as a list of values.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use custom formatter (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) for the column where you need to have `<br />`. This allow you to defina any HTML fragment for a column. See [jqGrid: Editable column that always shows a select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991267/jqgrid-editable-column-that-always-shows-a-select/2992064#2992064) as an example.

Probably [Wrapping Text lines in JqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730061/wrapping-text-lines-in-jqgrid) will be also helpful for you.

P.S. If you will have problems with the usage of custom formatter, post a column definition and a raw data example (JSON data for example) for the column where you want have `<br/>`

Comment: Thanks again Oleg.  I did implement a custom formatter, but the main result was achieved by me removing the usage of the ui-ellipsis CSS class on the columns and adding the style shown in your third post link.  Thanks for your help.