# show horizontal scroll bar in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Please see the link below,

http://www.logicatrix.com/example/records.html

In this table there are many columns included , so what i want is to get fit the whole table into
drawn gray border i.e. div element with class name bms-dashboard-body. with a horizontal scroll bar just like an excel sheet has on the right bottom corner a small one.
is it possible to create liquid layout of this jqgrid table ?

if someone has another approach , to fit the this table then i don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `autoWidth:true` should be written as `autowidth:true`.

Moreover you can set grid height and width with respect of `setGridHeight` and `setGridWidth` methods (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods). The best place to do this probably inside of the [loadComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event handler.

Comment: Using autowidth:true is causing problem because if i specify width of cloumns in a colModel then few of my cells are getting crushed :(

Comment: At least the value `autoWidth` is unknown for jqGrid and will be just ignored. There are different approach to place long information in jqGrid. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730061/wrapping-text-lines-in-jqgrid and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097498/render-a-newline-in-my-data-inside-a-jqgrid-cell/3097678#3097678. But in the most cases cutting  of information and displaying the full texts as tooltips are enough.

Answer (score 0):

you can get horizontal scroll bar with static or auto size fields by wrapping the grid and pager with a div and run a small script,
you can see the [jsfiddle-example](http://jsfiddle.net/yakirmanor/fQV7w/), or just go like so:

```
<div id="grid_container">
  <table id="list"></table>
  <div id="pager"></div>
</div>
```

and run this script:

```
$('#grid_container div:not(.ui-jqgrid-titlebar)').width("100%");
```

my example is using the script from trirand.com but iv tried it on their newest release and it worked just fine.
hope i've helped.