# Implement jqGrid in a table-less CSS layout

Tags: jquery, css, layout, jqgrid

I was just wondering if anyone has implemented jqGrid in a table-less, i.e. div-based layout.
This would basically require change to the JS that generates the table, and the CSS to handle overflows & text-warping.

Comment: Interesting, though I'm curious why this is desirable?

Comment: Although I do try to get away from tables in pages, this is one where I think it is a valid valued use of a table tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of "table-less design" is not simply to ditch the `<table>` tag. The `<table>` tag is still perfectly valid.

The point is that you are supposed to only use it now in places that are actually tables (ie an array of tabular data), rather than for doing page layout, as everyone used to do.

jqGrid is a JQuery plug-in that draws a block of tabular data. It is a perfect example of where the `<table>` tag should still be used. Using a table here meets all the criteria of modern web design patterns, because the `<table>` tag has a semantic meaning, because it is being used to display a table.

You should therefore keep using tables for this purpose.

Throwing out legitimate uses of tables like this is taking the concept of table-less design too far. You don't need to be - and you shouldn't be - that dogmatic about.

Answer (score 1):

jqGrid use `table-layout:fixed` style for the tables. The usage of pure div solution with `display:table-cell`, `display: table-row` and so on will work in less browsers as with `<table>`. It seems to me that one will also not receive real performance or other advantages.

You should probably more explain **why** you see an advantage in rewriting of existing solution in divs. It you need text-warping for example you can do use it in jqGrid (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730061/wrapping-text-lines-in-jqgrid) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641400/problem-with-wrapping-jqgrid-column-headers-on-ie) old answers)